# Ways to invoke Linux kernel memory allocation?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am examining how kernel memory allocators work (SLAB and SLUB). To trick them into being called, I need to invoke kernel memory allocations via a user-land program.

The obvious way would be calling syscall.fork(), which would generate process instances, for which the kernel must maintain PCB structures, which require a fair amount of memory space.

Then I'm out. I would not limit my experiments to merely calling fork() and trace them using Systemtap. Any other convenient ways to do the similar, but may requiring kernel objects (other than proc_t) with various features (the most important of which: their sizes)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SLUB` is just an efficient way (in comparison with `SLAB`) of managing the cache objects. It is more or less the same thing. You can read [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/229984/) why SLUB was introduced and [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand011.html) link talks about what exactly slab allocator is. Now on to tracing what exactly happens in kernel and how to trace it:

1. The easier but inefficient way is to read the source code but for that you need to know from where to start in the source.
2. Another way, more accurate, is to write a driver that allocates memory using `kmem_cache_create()` and then call it from your user program. Now you have a well defined start point, use `kgdb` and step through the entire  sequence.